# MongoDB $geoNear in aggregation pipeline with the latest Java-Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

Ok what I am trying to do is to find the proper way to add $geoNear in the aggregation pipeline. I have managed to do that, by adding a org.bson.Document at aggregation pipeline List, but I think there should be a more clear way to implement it with the latest official mongoDB Java-Driver. For instance, in order to do that for $group, $project, $match, mongoDB Java-Driver provides Aggregates class and the relevant calls are:

`Aggregates.group`,`Aggregates.project`,`Aggregates.match`. What I am looking for is something like: `Aggregates.geoNear`, which is abscent. My example code looks like this:

```
createDocumentCollection()
            .aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                    // geoNear spherical geometry for 2d sphere
                    new Document("$geoNear", new Document()
                        .append("near", new Document()
                            .append("$geometry", new Document()
                                .append("type", "Point")
                                .append("coordinates", Arrays.asList(longitude, latitude)))
                            .append("$maxDistance", maxDistance))
                        .append("key", "avgGeoPoint")
                        .append("distanceField", "dist.calculated")),
                    // group
                    Aggregates.group("$mmsi",
                        Accumulators.first("mmsi", "$mmsi"),
                        Accumulators.first("vesselName", "$vesselName"),
                        Accumulators.first("shipType", "$shipType")),
                    // projection
                    Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(
                        Projections.excludeId(),
                        Projections.include("mmsi", "vesselName", "shipType"))),
                    // skip
                    Aggregates.skip(options.getSkip()),
                    // limit
                    Aggregates.limit(options.getLimit())))
            .map(ModelExtractor::extractPlainVessel)
            .forEach((Consumer<PlainVessel>) nearVessels::add);
```

The part I am trying to replace is this:

```
new Document("$geoNear", new Document()
           .append("near", new Document()
               .append("$geometry", new Document()
                   .append("type", "Point")
                   .append("coordinates", Arrays.asList(longitude, latitude)))
               .append("$maxDistance", maxDistance))
            .append("key", "avgGeoPoint")
            .append("distanceField", "dist.calculated"))
```

Comment: You are right about there should be a cleaner way. However, as you mentioned Aggregates class does support for geoNear at the moment (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/8574c6daff4b8a1ecf65c67a301287bc919b5b7c/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.java). As far as I find, there are 31 possible stages for Aggregation pipeline (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/). I believe they implemented most frequently used ones so far or maybe they didn't have time to work on geoNear yet.

Comment: Then, @relativelyPrime, as for mongodb Java driver version 4.1, this is the way to implement geoNear in aggregation pipeline, right?

Comment: I would say yes as I couldn't find a cleaner alternative.